# How to identify the modern and Classic pages using PowerShell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

How to identify the page is a classic or modern using PowerShell? Use SharePoint Online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern site pages, at the moment are identifiable by 2 content types.

1) Site pages - Content Type Id - `0x0101009D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C4118`

2) Repost Page - Content Type Id - `0x0101009D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C4118002A50BFCFB7614729B56886FADA02339B`

Using this information, we can filter pages which are modern site pages using PnP PowerShell as below:

```
$cred = Get-Credential  

Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/test -Credential $cred  

Get-PnPListItem -List "Site Pages" -Query "<View><Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId'/><Value Type='ContentTypeId'>0x0101009D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C4118</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query></View>"
```